# JavaScript: Parameter not passed to Array.forEach inside of the function => undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, scope

```js
const data = {
  "desk": {
    "drawer": "stapler"
  },
  "cabinet": {
    "top drawer": { 
      "folder1": "a file",
      "folder2": "secrets"
    },
    "bottom drawer": "soda"
  },
  "item" : [
    {
      "hello" : {
        "world" : "isHere"
      },
      "test" : "1"
    },
        {
      "hello" : {
        "world" : "isHere2"
      },
      "test" : "2"
    },
    ]
};

const iterate = (obj) => {
  
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {

    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            iterate(obj[key])
    } else{
        let value = obj[key];
        let newObj = {[key]: value, 'style' : {backGroundColor : 'red'}};
        delete obj[key];
        Object.assign(obj, newObj);
    }
    })
}

iterate(data);
console.log(data)
```

I have wrote a recursive function that should replace each key-value pair (not property!) with a object that i specify in the parameter.

However, if I use a *array.forEach* loop inside the function, the passed *obj* is **undefined**.

What am I missing?

**Example**

---

```
const iterate = (obj, newObj) => {

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {

    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            iterate(obj[key])
    } else{
        delete obj[key];
        Object.assign(obj, newObj);
    }
    })
}
```

However, if I define the object within the forEach, it works perfectly ....

```
const iterate = (obj) => {

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {

    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
            iterate(obj[key])
    } else{
        let value = obj[key];
        
        // SEE HERE
        let newObj = {[key]: value, 'style' : {backGroundColor : 'red'}};

        delete obj[key];
        Object.assign(obj, newObj);
    }
    })
}
```

Why does the *Object.keys(obj).forEach* not see the passed parameter in the first version?
And what is the solution?

Comment: Please add some example data, and an expected result.

Comment: @OriDrori did it. This is the second version, however i want to pass a new Object as parameter to the function, but .forEach does not see the scope.

Comment: There is no declaration for `newObj` in the first code. `value` is unused. Is this a typo? I get the error message `ReferenceError: newObj is not defined"`

Comment: @jabaa Yes, value was deleted. What do you mean by declaration? it is given as parameter and should be passed until i call *Object.assign()*

Comment: The anonymous function that is assigned to `iterate` has two parameters but you always call it with one argument. The parameter `newObj` is always `undefined`. `Object.assign(obj, newObj);` is always `Object.assign(obj, undefined);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `newObj` whenever you call `iterate` inside the `Array.forEach()` - `iterate(obj[key], newObj)`:

```js
const data = {"desk":{"drawer":"stapler"},"cabinet":{"top drawer":{"folder1":"a file","folder2":"secrets"},"bottom drawer":"soda"},"item":[{"hello":{"world":"isHere"},"test":"1"},{"hello":{"world":"isHere2"},"test":"2"}]};

const iterate = (obj, newObj) => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      iterate(obj[key], newObj)
    } else {
      // delete obj[key]; // remove for example purposes
      Object.assign(obj, newObj);
    }
  })
}

const newObj = {
  'style': {
    backGroundColor: 'red'
  }
};

iterate(data, newObj);
console.log(data)
```